# nginx.conf file load-balacing issue like user load

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing, ubuntu-16.04, nginx-reverse-proxy

This is my nginx.conf default file but what i do when face more user load on nginx. what configuration add & edit in file?? how to face load-balcing issue? in ubuntu?`nginx`pleazz help to soul this issue

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
    }

    http {
    server {
    listen       127.0.0.1:80;
    listen       [::1]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
    }
    }


    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json         application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    #Virtual Host Configs

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;



    #mail {
    # See sample authentication script at:
    # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript

    # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";

    #server {
    #        listen     localhost:110;
    #       protocol   pop3;
    #       proxy      on;
    #}

    #server {
    #       listen     localhost:143;
    #       protocol   imap;
    #       proxy      on;
    #}
    #}
```